# node.js Write file with directories?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

If I use fs.writeFile I get:

```
Error: ENOENT, No such file or directory
```

I think that's because the directories that houses the file doesn't exist.

Am I supposed to use fs.mkdir first or is there something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js lacks a recursive directory creator in the core API.

Someone is yet to make something equivalent to Perl's [File::Path](http://search.cpan.org/~dland/File-Path-2.08/Path.pm), but here's at least a recursive creator in Node:

https://github.com/isaacs/npm/blob/master/lib/utils/mkdir-p.js

**Edit:**
This is probably easier to use: https://github.com/bpedro/node-fs

Comment: FYI, The link to mkdir-p.js is broken