# How to write file if parent folder doesn't exist?

Tags: node.js, file, file-io

I need to write file to the following path:

```js
fs.writeFile('/folder1/folder2/file.txt', 'content', function () {…});
```

But `'/folder1/folder2'` path may not exists. So I get the following error:

> message=ENOENT, open /folder1/folder2/file.txt

How can I write content to that path?

Comment: `fs.promises.mkdir(path.dirname('/folder1/folder2/file.txt'), {recursive: true}).then(x => fs.promises.writeFile('/folder1/folder2/file.txt', 'content'))`

Answer (score 164, accepted):

As of Node v10, this is built into the [fs.mkdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_options_callback) function, which we can use in combination with [path.dirname](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_dirname_p):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var getDirName = require('path').dirname;

function writeFile(path, contents, cb) {
  fs.mkdir(getDirName(path), { recursive: true}, function (err) {
    if (err) return cb(err);

    fs.writeFile(path, contents, cb);
  });
}
```

For older versions, you can use [mkdirp](https://npmjs.org/package/mkdirp):

```
var mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
var fs = require('fs');
var getDirName = require('path').dirname;

function writeFile(path, contents, cb) {
  mkdirp(getDirName(path), function (err) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    
    fs.writeFile(path, contents, cb);
  });
}
```

If the whole path already exists, `mkdirp` is a noop. Otherwise it creates all missing directories for you.

This module does what you want: https://npmjs.org/package/writefile . Got it when googling for "writefile mkdirp". This module returns a promise instead of taking a callback, so be sure to read some introduction to promises first. It might actually complicate things for you.

The function I gave works in any case.

Comment: So if we want to wait for it to complete we have to put everything after it into the callback? Is there some other way?

Comment: @pete if you use babel, you could go with async/await like this gist: https://gist.github.com/lucasreppewelander/9c87115b28cbd5d556e22b500deb555c

Comment: Use recursive: `fs.promises.mkdir(path.dirname(file), {recursive: true}).then(x => fs.promises.writeFile(file, data))`

Comment: Use [`fs.mkdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsmkdirsyncpath-options) for the synchronous version.

Answer (score 40):

**Edit**

NodeJS version [`10.12.0`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V10.md#2018-10-10-version-10120-current-targos) has added a native support for both `mkdir` and `mkdirSync` to create the parent director recursively with [`recursive: true`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_options) option as the following:

```
fs.mkdirSync(targetDir, { recursive: true });
```

And if you prefer [`fs Promises API`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api), you can write

```
fs.promises.mkdir(targetDir, { recursive: true });
```

### Original Answer

Create the parent directories recursively if they do not exist! (**Zero dependencies**)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function mkDirByPathSync(targetDir, { isRelativeToScript = false } = {}) {
  const sep = path.sep;
  const initDir = path.isAbsolute(targetDir) ? sep : '';
  const baseDir = isRelativeToScript ? __dirname : '.';

  return targetDir.split(sep).reduce((parentDir, childDir) => {
    const curDir = path.resolve(baseDir, parentDir, childDir);
    try {
      fs.mkdirSync(curDir);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.code === 'EEXIST') { // curDir already exists!
        return curDir;
      }

      // To avoid `EISDIR` error on Mac and `EACCES`-->`ENOENT` and `EPERM` on Windows.
      if (err.code === 'ENOENT') { // Throw the original parentDir error on curDir `ENOENT` failure.
        throw new Error(`EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '${parentDir}'`);
      }

      const caughtErr = ['EACCES', 'EPERM', 'EISDIR'].indexOf(err.code) > -1;
      if (!caughtErr || caughtErr && curDir === path.resolve(targetDir)) {
        throw err; // Throw if it's just the last created dir.
      }
    }

    return curDir;
  }, initDir);
}
```

#### Usage

```
// Default, make directories relative to current working directory.
mkDirByPathSync('path/to/dir');

// Make directories relative to the current script.
mkDirByPathSync('path/to/dir', {isRelativeToScript: true});

// Make directories with an absolute path.
mkDirByPathSync('/path/to/dir');
```

#### Demo

[**Try It!**](https://rextester.com/RYCC11960)

#### Explanations

- **[UPDATE]** This solution handles platform-specific errors like `EISDIR` for Mac and `EPERM` and `EACCES` for Windows.
- This solution handles both **relative** and **absolute** paths.
- In the case of relative paths, target directories will be created (resolved) in the current working directory. To Resolve them relative to the current script dir, pass `{isRelativeToScript: true}`.
- Using [`path.sep`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_sep) and [`path.resolve()`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths), not just `/` concatenation, to avoid cross-platform issues.
- Using [`fs.mkdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_mode) and handling the error with `try/catch` if thrown to handle race conditions: another process may add the file between the calls to [`fs.existsSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path) and [`fs.mkdirSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_mode) and causes an exception.

  - The other way to achieve that could be checking if a file exists then creating it, I.e, `if (!fs.existsSync(curDir) fs.mkdirSync(curDir);`. But this is an anti-pattern that leaves the code vulnerable to race conditions.
- Requires **Node v6** and newer to support destructuring. (If you have problems implementing this solution with old Node versions, just leave me a comment)

Answer (score 37):

I find that the easiest way to do this is to use the **[outputFile](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/master/docs/outputFile.md)**() method from the [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) module.

> Almost the same as writeFile (i.e. it overwrites), except that if the parent directory does not exist, it's created. options are what you'd pass to fs.writeFile().

Example:

```
var fs = require('fs-extra');
var file = '/tmp/this/path/does/not/exist/file.txt'

fs.outputFile(file, 'hello!', function (err) {
    console.log(err); // => null

    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        console.log(data); // => hello!
    });
});
```

It also has promise support out of the box these days!.

Answer (score 22):

Perhaps most simply, you can just use the [fs-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-path) npm module.

Your code would then look like:

```
var fsPath = require('fs-path');

fsPath.writeFile('/folder1/folder2/file.txt', 'content', function(err){
  if(err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    console.log('wrote a file like DaVinci drew machines');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

With node-fs-extra you can do it easily.

**Install it**

```
npm install --save fs-extra
```

Then use the **outputFile** method instead of **writeFileSync**

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');

fs.outputFile('tmp/test.txt', 'Hey there!', err => {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('The file was saved!');
  }
})
```

Comment: Node's been able to do natively since 2018. `fs-extra` is useful if you need all the libs it wraps, but if you _just_ need `mkdir -p` functionality, that's been built into Node's fs.mkdir since v10

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
fs.stat('/folder1/folder2', function(err, stats){ ... });
```

`stats` is a `fs.Stats` type of object, you may check `stats.isDirectory()`. Depending on the examination of `err` and `stats` you can do something, `fs.mkdir( ... )` or throw an error.

[Reference](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

Update: Fixed the commas in the code.

Comment: So I can't to write file by using the sibgle command in nodejs?

Answer (score 4):

Here's my custom function to recursively create directories (with no external dependencies):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var myMkdirSync = function(dir){
    if (fs.existsSync(dir)){
        return
    }

    try{
        fs.mkdirSync(dir)
    }catch(err){
        if(err.code == 'ENOENT'){
            myMkdirSync(path.dirname(dir)) //create parent dir
            myMkdirSync(dir) //create dir
        }
    }
}

myMkdirSync(path.dirname(filePath));
var file = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
```

Comment: Note that as of Node v10 this solution became moot with the introduction of https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_mkdir_path_options, which takes a "recursive" option.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my function which works in Node 10.12.0. Hope this will help.

```
const fs = require('fs');
function(dir,filename,content){
        fs.promises.mkdir(dir, { recursive: true }).catch(error => { console.error('caught exception : ', error.message); });
        fs.writeFile(dir+filename, content, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.info('file saved!');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let name = "./new_folder/" + file_name + ".png";
await driver.takeScreenshot().then(
  function(image, err) {
    require('mkdirp')(require('path').dirname(name), (err) => {
      require('fs').writeFile(name, image, 'base64', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/)

Answer (score -2):

In Windows you can use this code:

```
 try {  
   fs.writeFileSync(  './/..//..//filename.txt' , 'the text to write in the file', 'utf-8' );
     }
 catch(e){ 
  console.log(" catch XXXXXXXXX "); 
    }
```

This code in windows create file in 2 folder above the current folder.

> but I Can't create file in C:\ Directly