# writeFile no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, fs

I have a file(`data.file` an image), I would like to save this image. Now an image with the same name *could* exist before it. I would like to overwrite if so or create it if it does not exist since before. I read that the flag "w" should do this.

Code:

```js
fs.writeFile('/avatar/myFile.png', data.file, {
  flag: "w"
}, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Error:

> ```
> [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/avatar/myFile.png']
> errno: -2,
>   code: 'ENOENT',
>     syscall: 'open',
>       path: '/avatar/myFile.png'
> ```

Answer (score 151, accepted):

This is probably because you are trying to write to root of file system instead of your app directory `'/avatar/myFile.png'` -> `__dirname + '/avatar/myFile.png'` should do the trick, also check if folder exists. node.js won't create parent folder for you.

Comment: Knew it was something trivial, ta.

Comment: The issue I was having was the parent directory didn't exist. Thanks for the tip

Comment: how to write the file in different machine in node js. I am tried with path instead of url(http://example.com/files/) but its given the same error. Is possible to upload the file in different server?

Comment: To do so you need to use proper package to upload via SFTP / FTP / whatever. Or you need to have other server linked (So it is accessible via file system, on windows it should have disk letters assigned, on linux mounted)

Answer (score 47):

Many of us are getting this error because **parent path** does not exist. E.g. you have `/tmp` directory available but there is no folder "foo" and you are writing to `/tmp/foo/bar.txt`.

To solve this, you can use [`mkdirp`](https://npmjs.org/package/mkdirp) - adapted from [How to write file if parent folder doesn't exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16317628/1366033)

#### Option A) Using Callbacks

```js
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
const fs = require('fs');
const getDirName = require('path').dirname;

function writeFile(path, contents, cb) {
  mkdirp(getDirName(path), function (err) {
    if (err) return cb(err);

    fs.writeFile(path, contents, cb);
  });
}
```

#### Option B) Using Async/Await

Or if you have an environment where you can use async/await:

```js
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
const fs = require('fs');

const writeFile = async (path, content) => {
  await mkdirp(path);
  fs.writeFileSync(path, content);
}
```

Comment: Question, why await `writeFileSync`?

Comment: @eestein good point, no need. Updated. But there is no difference in this case while fs.writeFileSync is just converted to the resolved promise which does nothing in this context. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: `mkdirp` has been made redundant by the addition of a `recursive` option for `fs.mkDir`. [Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_options_callback).

Answer (score 23):

I solved a similar problem where I was trying to create a file with a name that contained characters that are not allowed. Watch out for that as well because it gives the same error message.

Comment: Thanks for this! That's exactly why I was getting it.

Comment: This answer should be higher, for visibility purposes. I was in a cross-platform setup and Jenkins was killing my jobs due to this exact thing. The invalid chard on Windows were the issue. Bless you man!

Answer (score 18):

I ran into this error when creating some nested folders asynchronously right before creating the files. The destination folders wouldn't always be created before promises to write the files started. I solved this by using `mkdirSync` instead of 'mkdir' in order to create the folders synchronously.

```
try {
    fs.mkdirSync(DestinationFolder, { recursive: true } );
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Cannot create folder ', e);
}
fs.writeFile(path.join(DestinationFolder, fileName), 'File Content Here', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: This is solution and the answer below are very closely related

Answer (score 10):

Actually, the error message for the file names that are not allowed in Linux/ Unix system comes up with the same error which is extremely confusing. Please check the file name if it has any of the reserved characters. These are the reserved ***/, >, <, |, :, &*** characters for Linux / Unix system. For a good read follow this [link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linuxunix-rules-for-naming-file-and-directory-names/).

Comment: This resolved my issue on Windows10 as well - Trying to write a file using Date.toIsoString() in the filename contained colons. Replacing the colons fixed the error.

Answer (score 7):

It tells you that the `avatar` folder does not exist.
Before writing a file into this folder, you need to check that a directory called `"avatar"` exists and if it doesn't, create it:

```
   if (!fs.existsSync('/avatar')) {
      fs.mkdirSync('/avatar', { recursive: true});
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use './' as a prefix for your path.

in your example, you will write:

```
fs.writeFile('./avatar/myFile.png', data.file, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log("The file was saved!");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

*I* had this error because I tried to run:

```
fs.writeFile(file)
fs.unlink(file)
...lots of code... probably not async issue...
fs.writeFile(file)
```

in the same script. The exception occurred on the second `writeFile` call. Removing the first two calls solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I use async `fs.mkdir()` and then, **without waiting for this task to complete**, I tried to create a file `fs.writeFile()`...

Answer (score 0):

As [SergeS mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34811359/6225838), using `/` attempts to write in your system root folder, but instead of using **__dirname**, which points to the path of the file where *writeFile* is invoked, you can use **process.cwd()** to point to the project's directory. Example:

```
writeFile(`${process.cwd()}/pictures/myFile.png`, data, (err) => {...});
```

If you want to avoid string concatenations/interpolations, you may also use `path.join(process.cwd(), 'pictures', 'myFile.png')` (more details, including directory creation, in this [digitalocean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-how-to-use__dirname)).