# How to read a file and log its content in node js

Tags: node.js, events, fs

How to read the contents of a file by using the `fs` core module of Node, and log the contents into the console using `events`. I tried the below code but yet not worked. Is there any other way? I'm new to node

```
events= require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
fs = require('fs');


var Myfunc = function () {
 fs.readFile('./new-dir/sample.txt', function(err, data){
  if(err){
   console.log(err);
  }
  else{
   console.log(data.toString());
  }
 });
}

eventEmitter.on('MyEvent', Myfunc);
eventEmitter.emit('MyEvent');
```

Comment: What is the error message? I ran above code and they work fine.

Comment: no errors were shown. getting  incorrect path error when using readFileSync.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44814679/13126651 will help you